# Liquibase 3.3.2 is failing with exception ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object

Tags: spring, oracle, spring-boot, liquibase

I am using Liquibase as part of Spring boot program.

Earlier we were have normal Java Web application and we used to run the Liquibase manually with version liquibase-3.0.2.

Now as part of Liquibase+Spring boot, we are trying to run the Liquibase on same oracle database. so only Application is changed not database.

In my pom.xml

I am using

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

or

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

So with latest Liquibase version whenever I am trying to deploy the application getting the error

```
CONSOLE: 15:18:53.190 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  liquibase - Reading from SCHEMAMETA.DATABASECHANGELOG
CONSOLE: 15:18:53.600 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR liquibase - classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml: classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-1.0.xml::001_create_ABC_TABLE::tcolson: Change Set classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-1.0.xml::001_create_ABC_TABLE::tcolson failed.  Error: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object
```

I am getting the same exceptions using both versions of mavan. 
It should say Ok, all is already deployed, nothing to do here. But Looks like Liquibase is failing even in verifying the existing entries.

Please let me know the catch here or any solution.

Comment: Hi, Tried to use old Liquibase version 3.0.2 but getting org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.boot.liquibase.CommonsLoggingLiquibaseLogger.buildMessage(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;

Comment: Is the location path of your changeset (`classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-1.0.xml`) the same as before? By finding the changesets to execute I think Liquibase will also compare the path of the already executed changeset.

Comment: I am not sure about the problem. But when i am running the Liquibase manually, then it's running properly.                               /apps/share/liquibase/liquibase \--driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver \--url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@testdb:1524:TESTSTG" \--classpath="/apps/share/tomcat/webapps/mgr3/WEB-INF/lib/ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar" \--changeLogFile="db.changelog-master.xml" \--username=SCHEMA \--password=password migrate

Answer (score 2):

This issue is same as `liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-02264: name already used by an existing constraint`
This is not related to Liquibase 3.3.2 version.

First you should run below command after that you will be able to execute liquibase update successfully.

command: `./liquibase changeLogSync`